# Convert Epoch to DateTime SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Apologies my cap broke mid title.

I'm having issues with the following:

```
dateadd(S, [unixtime], '1970-01-01')
```

to convert epoch to `datetime` in SQL Server, but received the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Obviously it means the epoch is too big for `int`? even though this code has worked previously; bizarrely. is there a way to call this with bigint?

eg epoch:

```
1440753397054
```

and I believe the limit is 10 digits, so an alternative?

Comment: What are your typical values in [unixtime]? Are you sure they are seconds and not milliseconds, i.e. x1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp is in *milli*seconds. Try dividing it by 1000 and I'm sure it will work.

`1440753397054 / 1000 = 1440753397,054` corresponds to (assuming GMT):

**Fri, 28 Aug 2015 09:16:37 GMT**

Comment: tested in sql server, need to remove the 3 last digits in c#, thanks.