# Convert Epoch to DateTime SQL Server (Exceeds Year 2038)

Tags: sql-server, limit, epoch, year2038

How to convert Epoch to DateTime SQL Server if epoch exceeds the year 2038?

Answer in [Convert Epoch to DateTime SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267688/convert-epoch-to-datetime-sql-server) will not work.

Example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ss, 2713795200000 / 1000, '19700101')
```

Thu, 30 Dec 2055 16:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATEADD function assumes an INT as an increment to your date, to bypass the limitation of INT you can either reduce the precision of your epoch, or do a slightly complex code to retain the precision of your epoch.

This reduces the precision to minutes:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,@YourEpoch/60/1000, '1/1/1970')
```

This one splits your epoch to days and milliseconds and then combines them in a datetime

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_EpochToDatetime] (@Epoch BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Days AS INT, @MilliSeconds AS INT
    SET @Days = @Epoch / (1000*60*60*24)
    SET @MilliSeconds = @Epoch % (1000*60*60*24)

    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @MilliSeconds, DATEADD(DAY, @Days, '1/1/1970')))
END;
```

However, I'm not quite sure why the 2nd solution is not as precise as I expect it to be.

Comment: 1. [DateTime] is only accurate to 3⅓ milliseconds. Try having your function return a DATETIME2(3).

Comment: 2. Modulo works when both parameters are positive. Instead try: `SET @Days = SIGN(@Epoch) * FLOOR(ABS(@Epoch) / (1000*60*60*24));` and `SET @MilliSeconds = SIGN(@Epoch) * (ABS(@Epoch) % (1000*60*60*24));`

Answer (score 0):

Building on the response above, the solution provided works but does not protect from trying to convert to a date that is out of bounds for SQL server.

create function dbo.unixTimestampConversion (
@unixTime bigInt
)
returns dateTime2(7)
as
begin

```
    declare
        @output dateTime2(7)
        , @days int
        , @ms   int
        , @x    int = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    ;


    set @days = @unixTime / @x
    ;
    set @ms = @unixTime % @x
    ;
    if (@unixTime < 32503593600000 and @unixTime > -2208988800000)
        begin
            set @output = dateAdd (millisecond, @ms, dateAdd (day, @days, '1/1/1970'))
            ;
        end
        ;
    else if (@unixTime <= -2208988800000)
             begin
                 set @output = '1/1/1900'
                 ;
             end
             ;
    else if (@unixTime >= 32503593600000)
             begin
                 set @output = '12/31/2999'
                 ;
             end
             ;
    return @output
    ;


end
```

;

Comment: I tested this out. It does not fix the precision issue. I tested it with an epoch of 1628389678598. The value from https://www.epochconverter.com/ is 2021-08-08 02:27:58.598 . This answer returns 2021-08-08 02:27:58.5966667. Relying on DATEADD is the problem here, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the epoch time to your datetime directly (I tried this on SQL Server 15.0). Although it considers the number as the number of days since 1900-1-1 00:00:00 so you have to add 2208988800 (the number of seconds in 70 years) and then divide by 86400(number of seconds in a day).

```
DECLARE @time DATETIME = (2208988800.0 + [your epoch time in seconds])/86400;
```

However, it seems to be 0.007s or 0.003s behind the given epoch. Also, I'm not sure if this is faster than the `DATEADD()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but later versions of SQL Server that support the `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type have made this easier:

```
DATEADD(CAST('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' AS DATETIMEOFFSET),s,<epoch time as bigint>))
```

`DATEADD` can work with `s`/`second`, `ms`/`millisecond`, `mcs`/`microsecond`, and `ns`/`nanosecond`.

Then, if you need it in a specific time zone, use `SELECT <date> AS TIME ZONE <timezone>`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Your code has an extra parenthesis at the end, and the DATEADD parameters are in the wrong order. Try running them in the correct order, and I get an overflow error: `SELECT DATEADD(S, 2246996729, CAST('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' AS DATETIMEOFFSET))`

Answer (score -2):

create a function to convert epoch to datetime and use them in your query like 
below

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[from_unixtime] (@Datetime BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT
           ,@AdjustedLocalDatetime BIGINT;
    SET @LocalTimeOffset = DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
    SET @AdjustedLocalDatetime = @Datetime - @LocalTimeOffset
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(second,@AdjustedLocalDatetime, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)))
END;
```

and then use this function in your query

Comment: Throws an error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int." exactly because it exceeds Year 2038

Comment: cast the data type according to data size ..your error will get resolve