# How to remove TIME on Epoch in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, limit, epoch, year2038

How to remove TIME on Epoch format in SQL Server?

Example:
**2713795200000** should return **Thu, 30 Dec 2055 00:00:00** instead of **Thu, 30 Dec 2055 16:00:00 GMT.**

Comment: `CAST` it as a date and then back to datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query for your problem. May be its helps you.

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, (2713795200000)/(1000*60*60*24), '19700101')
```

Comment: Thanks sir! you could also answer my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300536/convert-epoch-to-datetime-sql-server-exceeds-year-2038/37300753?noredirect=1#comment62124520_37300753

Comment: @Dobermaxx99 Your Welcome : )