# Update epoch timestamp to dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss.ms

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, epoch, dateadd

I have column of timestamps named `a_timestamp` in table named `dataset4_do_edycji` - formatted as epoch timestamp. I need to update it do human readable in this format: dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss.ms. I tried using

```
UPDATE dataset4_do_edycji SET  a_timestamp=(select dateadd(ms, a_timestamp%(3600*24*1000), 
dateadd(day, a_timestamp/(3600*24*1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')))
```

However it throws error:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to bigint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

At the moment `a_timestamp` is declared as bigint. When I run the following it shows correct values:

```sql
select dateadd(ms, a_timestamp%(3600*24*1000), 
    dateadd(day, a_timestamp/(3600*24*1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')
) as a_timestamp
FROM dataset4_do_edycji
```

Is there any way to update it except downloading both files in CSV and combining them manually to one and later importing it as new table? Thank you.

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have a format; at best convert the epoch to a date and time value and then worry about the format in the presentation layer. As for how to do that, there are plenty of examples how to on [so], such as [converting Epoch timestamp to sql server(human readable format)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4787827/2029983), [Convert Epoch to DateTime SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32267688/2029983) and [Convert unix epoch timestamp to TSQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14507649/2029983).

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll check that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple method is to add a computed column:

```
alter table dataset4_do_edycji add a_timestamp_dt as
    (dateadd(ms, a_timestamp%(3600*24*1000), 
             dateadd(day, a_timestamp/(3600*24*1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')
            )
    )
```

The column value is then calculated when you query it, so it is always up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you, i suppose noone would be mad about leaving timestamp column still in. It worked :)